# Wordpress server side datatable filtering

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, datatables

I am currently working on a database dat needs to filter a 1.000.000 Products. For this I created 2 wordpress websites. 1 to show the data and 1 for storing the data.

Now I am first building the script in a plugin and displaying it on the data website. But now I keep struggeling with the filtering and I am questioning my current approach to handle over 1.000.000 products. (The products only need to be displayed with a form so it more like a catalog and not really a store.)

So the main question is. Is this the correct approach and is datatables.net a right way of doing this. The second question is how can I fix this filtering problem.

When the filtering is empty and noting is selected in the table I get 0 results so the

```
<?php
    // Exit if accessed directly.
    defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

    //encrypt('encrypt', $users[$x][1], $usertokens[$x][2], 'test')
    //decrypt('decrypt', $results[$i]->emergencyemailaddress, $results[$i]->token, 'test');
// Add Post title to custom meta 
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'duplicate_title', 10, 3 ); 

function duplicate_title( $new, $old, $post ) { 
  if ( $post->post_type == 'autos' ) { 
    update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'd_title', $post->post_title ); 
  } 
}
// Add DataTables Resources
 
function add_datatables_scripts() {
  wp_register_script('datatables', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('datatables');

  wp_register_script('datatables_bootstrap', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true);
  wp_enqueue_script('datatables_bootstrap');
}
 
function add_datatables_style() {
  wp_register_style('bootstrap_style', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_style');

  wp_register_style('datatables_style', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css');
  wp_enqueue_style('datatables_style');
}
 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_datatables_scripts');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_datatables_style');

function autos_datatables_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'autos_datatables', '/js/autostable.js?ver=1.0', array('jquery'),  true );
  wp_localize_script( 'autos_datatables', 'ajax_url', admin_url('admin-ajax.php?action=autos_datatables') );
}


// Add a function to retrieve available Merk options
function get_merk_options() {
    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'car_merk',
        'hide_empty' => true, // Include even terms with no posts
    ));

    $options = array();
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $options[] = $term->name;
    }

    return $options;
}

// Modify your shortcode or HTML to generate checkboxes dynamically
function generate_merk_checkboxes() {
    $merk_options = get_merk_options();

    $dropdown_html = '<div>';
    $dropdown_html .= '<label for="filter-merk">Selecteer merk:</label>';
    $dropdown_html .= '<select id="filter-merk" class="filter-merk">';
    $dropdown_html .= '<option value="">Selecteer merk</option>';

    foreach ($merk_options as $option) {
        $dropdown_html .= '<option value="' . $option . '">' . $option . '</option>';
    }

    $dropdown_html .= '</select>';
    $dropdown_html .= '</div>';

    return $dropdown_html;
}

// Update your autos_datatables function to include the generated checkboxes
function autos_datatables() {
    autos_datatables_scripts(); 

    ob_start(); ?> 
    
    <div>
        <?php echo generate_merk_checkboxes(); ?>
    </div>

    <table id="autostable" class="table table-striped table-hover"> 
        <thead> 
            <tr> 
                <th>Auto title</th>
                <th>brandstof</th>
                <th>Merk</th>
                <th>bouwjaar</th>
                <th>afbeelding</th>
            </tr> 
        </thead> 
    </table> 

    <?php return ob_get_clean(); 
}

add_shortcode ('autos_datatables', 'autos_datatables');

add_action('wp_ajax_autos_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_autos_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');


function datatables_server_side_callback() {
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $request = $_GET;

    $columns = array(
        0 => 'post_title',
        1 => 'car_brandstof',
        2 => 'car_merk', // Assuming 'Merk' is the third column
        3 => 'car_bouwjaar',
        4 => 'image_0',
    );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'cars',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => $request['length'],
        'offset' => $request['start'],
        'order' => $request['order'][0]['dir'],
    );

    if ($request['order'][0]['column'] == 0) {
        $args['orderby'] = $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']];
    } elseif ($request['order'][0]['column'] == 1 || $request['order'][0]['column'] == 2) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['meta_key'] = $columns[$request['order'][0]['column']];
    }

// Update the query to handle the merk_filter parameter
if (!empty($request['merk_filter'])) {
    $merk_terms = array_map('sanitize_text_field', $request['merk_filter']);
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'car_merk',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $merk_terms,
        'operator' => 'IN',
    );
}

// Add condition to include all posts when merk_filter is empty
if (empty($request['merk_filter'])) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'car_merk',
        'operator' => 'EXISTS', // Include all posts
    );
}
    // Other meta queries and search query

    $autos_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $totalData = $autos_query->found_posts;
    $data = array();

    if ($autos_query->have_posts()) {
        while ($autos_query->have_posts()) {
            $autos_query->the_post();

            // Your code to populate $data with results
            $nestedData = array();
            $nestedData[] = get_the_title();
            $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'car_brandstof');

            // Brandstof
            if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
                $brandstof = array();
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $brandstof[] = $term->name;
                }
                $nestedData[] = implode(', ', $brandstof);
            } else {
                $nestedData[] = '';
            }

            // Get the terms for the 'car_merk' taxonomy
            $merk_terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'car_merk');

            if ($merk_terms && !is_wp_error($merk_terms)) {
                $merk = array();
                foreach ($merk_terms as $term) {
                    $merk[] = $term->name;
                }
                $nestedData[] = implode(', ', $merk);
            } else {
                $nestedData[] = 'geen merk';
            }

            // Get the terms for the 'car_merk' taxonomy
            $merk_terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'car_bouwjaar');

            if ($merk_terms && !is_wp_error($merk_terms)) {
                $merk = array();
                foreach ($merk_terms as $term) {
                    $merk[] = $term->name;
                }
                $nestedData[] = implode(', ', $merk);
            } else {
                $nestedData[] = '';
            }

            // Get the URL of the first image and decode it from base64
            $image_base64 = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'image_0', true);
            $image_url = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $image_base64;
        
            // Wrap the image URL with an <img> tag
            $image_tag = '<img width="50px" src="' . $image_url . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '">';
        
            // Add the image tag to the nested data
            $nestedData[] = $image_tag;


            // Add the nested data to the main data array
            $data[] = $nestedData;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        wp_reset_query();
    }

    $json_data = array(
        "draw" => intval($request['draw']),
        "recordsTotal" => intval($totalData),
        "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalData),
        "data" => $data,
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);
    wp_die();
}
    
?>
```

Javascript:

```
$ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
    // DataTables initialization
    var table = $('#autostable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": ajax_url,
            "data": function(d) {
                // Get an array of checked Merk values
                var checkedMerks = $('.filter-merk').map(function() {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get();
                
                // If no selection is made, pass an empty array to the server
                if (checkedMerks.length === 0) {
                    checkedMerks = [''];
                }

                // Add the merk_filter parameter to the data object
                d.merk_filter = checkedMerks;

                return d;
            }
        }
    });

    // Checkbox change event handler
    $(document).on('change', '.filter-merk', function() {
        // Reload DataTables with new filter criteria
        table.ajax.reload();
    });
});
```

Comment: "Is this the correct approach and is datatables.net a right way of doing this" - We can't really answer that for you. My opinion is that step #1 is to get something to work, and then the optional step #2 is to make it work better, however "better" is subjective.

Comment: "When the filtering is empty and noting is selected in the table I get 0 results" - I didn't really read the code, but without a filter, then people are just browsing the data, so first, is that a feature you want? If so, then you need to come up with a "default filter", which for you is probably just a sort.